# moment.js vs none chrome browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

moment.js seems to only work with chrome.

tried Date.parse();

moment(now, 'YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:ss')
this works but it's not the correct timer, usually jumps back and forth between random numbers.

I tried, 
          if(chrome === true){
               ///do this
                     }
                      else{
                      //do that
                           }

nothing works, i'll either get NaN for the timer or the mumbled timer

here's the code

```
                 setInterval(function(){    
      start = getStartTime()

      ServerDate - new Date();
  var now= ServerDate.now();


   if(isChrome === true){
a = moment(now);
b = moment(start);
      }else{

a = now;
b = moment(start, 'YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:ss');

      }

ms = b.diff(a, 'milliseconds', true);
hours = Math.floor(moment.duration(ms).asHours());

b = b.subtract('hours', hours);
// update the duration in ms
ms = b.diff(a, 'milliseconds', true);
mins = Math.floor(moment.duration(ms).asMinutes());

b = b.subtract('minutes', mins);
// update the duration in ms
ms = b.diff(a, 'milliseconds', true);
secs = Math.floor(moment.duration(ms).asSeconds());

if(secs<10){
  secs ="0"+secs;
}

document.getElementById('grabbitTimerDiv').innerHTML='<small>starts in: </small>'+ mins +':'+secs;

      },1000);
```

Comment: Found the moment.countdown plug in... that doesnt work either

Comment: moment.js likely isn't broken across browsers here. It seems suspicious that the start is always "at the top of the interval". Anyway, create a http://jsfiddle.net (or equivalent) test-case. Also, remember that you need to run the interval *faster* than the period being observed (or otherwise be smart about running it) to be guaranteed of seeing every second.

Comment: It would help if you showed us sample values for your input parameters.  Also, the third line doesn't do anything at all, and you're using too many global variables.  Moment is certainly cross-browser.